# Combine one List element with second list list in scala

Tags: scala, list

In scala, I am having two lists. First list say L1 is one dimensional that contains roll numbers of students and second say L2 is n-dimensional that contains marks of subjects. Based on these two list I want to create a third list say L3 that takes first roll number(first element ) of L1 and concatenate it with first row of L2 and produces first row of L3 with first element is roll number and next are marks of subjects and so on do this till length of L1. Both L1 and L2 have same length. I tried following code but it does not work as desired

```
val L1 = List(1,2,3) // roll numbers
val L2 = List(List(34,67,21,56,87) ,List(65,21,34,98,77) , List(76,65,59,88,90)) // marks
      //I want L3 =List(List(1,34,67,21,56,87) , List(2,65,21,34,98,77) ,List(3,76,65,59,88,90))
val L3 = L1.map(x => x :: L2.map(row => row))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
val L1 = List(1,2,3) // roll numbers
val L2 = List(List(34,67,21,56,87) ,List(65,21,34,98,77) , List(76,65,59,88,90)) // marks

val L3 = (L1, L2).zipped.map(_ :: _)
```

Comment: Or `(L1, L2).zipped.map{case (a,b)=> a::b}` aka `(L1, L2).zipped.map(_ :: _)`.

Comment: The difference between `.zip(..).map` and `.zipped.map` is not only readability but also performance.

Comment: Surely it doesn't matter for 5 elements :)

Answer (score 1):

```
val L3 = L1.zip(L2).map(x => x._1 :: x._2)
```